# No output showing up for example functions

Tags: output

I am total beginner to Mathematica. I am following some examples from [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FunctionApproximations/tutorial/FunctionApproximations.html)

However, if I run some function, for example, `MiniMaxApproimation`, then I get no output.

[image: Following are few things I tried but nothing shows up as on website]

1]: [![https://i.stack.imgur.com/LC9Q8.png

However, on website the output looks like this:
[image]

Comment: As the mannual says, you need to run `<< FunctionApproximations\`` first.

Comment: I would add that you can observe the color: if a command is written in black--it is known to Mathematica. If a command is written blue--it is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Sumit's reply. Run this command before running fucntions

<< FunctionApproximations`